# Vb.net Outlook Security Issue

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

hi am working on a project that uses outlook to do different things. one of which is accessing emails and using them. the code below is the code i am using to get the emails

```
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()
    ' Get Mapi NameSpace.
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
    ' Get Messages collection of Inbox.
    Dim oInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder =         
    oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items = oInbox.Items
    oItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
    ' oItems = oItems.Sort("date", False)

    ' Loop each unread message.
    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each item As Object In oItems
        Try
            If (TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem) Then
                If i <= 100 Then
                    oMsg = item
                    Dim subject1 As String
                    Dim receivetime As String
                    Dim sender As String
                    Dim con As String
                    con = oMsg.Body
                    sender = oMsg.SenderName
                    subject1 = oMsg.Subject
                    receivetime = oMsg.ReceivedTime
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

this code trips the outlook security ever time and i am looking for code that does not trip it and that doesn't involve editing the registry or turning down my outlook security settings. thank you for your time

Comment: I'd be surprised if some arbitrary program accessing your email *didn't* raise a red flag, unless you change a setting somewhere in Outlook (or in the registry) to explicitly allow it.  Think about what could happen if i could bypass any security warnings just by using commands C and D instead of A and B.  Your email account would no longer be yours.

Comment: For reference: Is the security thing you're seeing similar to the one(s) mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb226711.aspx#section4126 ?  If so, that page has info that may help.  Also check out the various settings under Tools / Trust Center.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for the list of your options.

Essentially your options are Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), Redemption, or ClickYes.

Comment: stupid question but is there any type of certification that i could give my application or something i could get that will tell outlook that this application can be trusted ?

Comment: No, the only thing you can do is make sure you have up to date anti virus software. *If* you can control the user environment.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using the advice here:
http://www.slipstick.com/developer/change-programmatic-access-options/
He shows a step by step approach to enabling access to programs by running outlook as administrator.  Although I am concerned about the security so wouldn't recommend it to anyone using a computer that isn't behind some significant protection.